# WINDOWS LOCK SCREEN: Unable to refresh via Commandline

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, lock-screen

I'm trying to publish a LockScreen company-wide and I was able to achieve it by applying the settings under the registry *'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization'* and it worked as expected.

```
$RegistryPathPersonalization = 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization'

    If (-NOT (Test-Path $RegistryPathPersonalization)) {
        New-Item -Path $RegistryPathPersonalization -Force
    }

    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPathPersonalization -Name 'LockScreenImage' -Value 'C:\Windows\Web\CSImages\LockScreen.jpg' -PropertyType 'String'
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPathPersonalization -Name 'LockScreenOverlaysDisabled' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPathPersonalization -Name 'NoChangingLockScreen' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWORD'
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryPathPersonalization -Name 'NoLockScreenSlideshow' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWORD'
```

However when there are changes to the LockScreen file, we had to replace the file with a new file and they were named after the default naming convention, due to this even after successful modification, the LockScreen remains with the same old image and I could see the new image is been reflecting only under **Settings->Persnolization->LockScreen** setting applet.

If I'm not wrong, the LockScreen is cached somewhere and it's been using the old image even though the new files are updated on the same path. What would be the best way to maintain the LockScreen management via scripts?

Comment: Silly question, but have you rebooted and checked that its still not working after that?

Comment: Yup, multiple times... seems it's stuck with the same old\first image.

Comment: Could you share with us your registry settings ?

Comment: Just added them at the top, it's like we are applying a policy for the lock screen and it doesn't allow users to modify the settings as 'NoChangingLockScreen' set to 1.
I will be using the filename for the new image, maybe that's were the challenge kicks in. If I use different names, they are working as expected.